# getSerializableExtra() is null randomly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

There is a link in one activity, after I click on it it opens another activity. I add an `enum` parameter for the second activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding.myLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // ...
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivityContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY, MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // ...
}
```

In onCreate of second activity I read this parameter

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    // get value
    FirstActivity.MyEnum value = (FirstActivity.MyEnum ) getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra(AboutActivity.KEY);

    // ...
}
```

Everything works but in Crashlytics I see that for some users value is `null`. Second activity is called only from first one and from nowhere else.

Can someone suggest me the scenario with this behavior? When can it happen like this?

I opened my app, opened the second activity and put app to background. After several hours I opened my app from the list of apps and everything is ok. No more ideas when it can happen.

Answer (score -1):

use this :

```
     @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivityContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(serializableKEY,yourSerializableClass);
                intent.putExtras(KEY, bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

and in second activity :

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
yourSerializableClass clazz=(yourSerializableClass)bundle.getSerializable(serializableKEY);
```